# node.js imqplib sendToQueue to RabbitMQ is hanging

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a function for queuing a message to RabbitMQ like so:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

var _queueURL = 'amqp://127.0.0.1';
var _toBlahBlahQueueName = 'blahblah';

var self = module.exports = {
  queueMessage: function (msgObj, callback) {
    try {
      amqp.connect(_queueURL, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err);
        }

        connection.createChannel(function (err, channel) {
          if (err) {
            callback(err);
          }

          channel.assertQueue(_toBlahBlahQueueName, { durable: true }, function (err, _ok) {
            if (err) {
              callback(err);
            }

            var msg = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(msgObj));

            channel.sendToQueue(_toBlahBlahQueueName, msg, { persistent: true }, function (err, ok) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err);
              }

              console.log('published', ok);

              channel.connection.close();
              callback(null, { message: 'queued' });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
      callback(e);
    }
  }
};
```

I am calling the function queueMessage with messages that are about 250K in length.

The sendToQueue call is hanging every time.  It just sits there without returning an error.  However, the message seems to get queued!

The server log has the error message: client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

amqplib does not support callback for `sendToQueue` or `publish`.

[the documentation](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_sendToQueue) shows this is not an option:

> Channel#sendToQueue
>   Promises and callbacks
>
> sendToQueue(queue, content, [options])
>
> Send a single message with the content given as a buffer to the specific
>   queue named, bypassing routing. The options and return value are exactly
>   the same as for publish.

To work around this, you need to call `sendToQueue` as if it were a synchronous message.

If you want to immediately exit the app, you will have to wait a few milliseconds before doing so. Failure to do that will result in the message not being sent.

Here is an example of how you could change your code to work this way:

```
channel.sendToQueue(_toBlahBlahQueueName, msg, { persistent: true });
setTimeout(function () {
  channel.connection.close();
  callback(null, { message: 'queued' });
}, 500);
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  Is there a library that does this better?  Seems inefficient.   One last question if I may... What's the best way to send multiple messages in series?  Do I have to open the connection and channel and assert queue for each message?  Or can I, say, assert queue and then send a pile of messages?  Thanks!!

Comment: sadly, no, there isn't. amqplib is the standard library that even the rabbitmq team recommend, for node.js. there are other libraries built on top of amqplib, that make some things easier... but none of them have a good solution for this particular scenario.

Comment: Now you can use `await channel.close(); await connection.close()` and the message will be delivered!

Answer (score 1):

If you need support for callbacks or promises another solution may be to use the "ConfirmChannel" RabbitMQ extension.

**> [RabbitMQ ConfirmChannel docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)**

**> [amqplib ConfirmChannel API](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#confirmchannel)**

My issue was that the Node.js process was exiting before the message had actually finished sending, even though `ch.sendToQueue()` had returned `true`.

My solution was to change `conn.createChannel()` to `conn.createConfirmChannel()` which allowed me to `await ch.sendToQueue()`. That may be useful for you but bear in mind it will incur additional overhead.